# Fetching same vertex data for multiple levels in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I am a beginner in OrientDB.

Consider that I have 2 Vertex, `Cat` and `Val`.
`Cat` contains a property called `category` and `Val` contains a property called `value`.

Categories can have sub-categories and those can further have sub-categories and so on. The categories and sub-categories are stored in Vertex `Cat`. The sub-categories are mapped using an edge called `CatEdge` whose `from` and `to` are the same vertex i.e. `Cat`.

For example, consider a category 'Education' which has two sub-categories 'School' and 'College'. The 'College' sub-category has further sub-categories 'Bachelors' and 'Masters'. So, there will be an edge in `CatEdge` from 'Education' to 'School' and 'College', and from 'College' to 'Bachelors' and 'Masters'.

```
Education
   |- School
   |- College
        |- Bachelors
        |- Masters
```

Apart from these, the `Cat` Vertex can have categories that do not have any sub-categories, for example 'FirstName', 'LastName', etc.

All the 'leaf' categories (that do not have further sub-category) have an edge called `ValEdge` from Vertex `Cat` to Vertex `Val`.

I want to retrieve all 'value' from `Val` for all the categories and sub-categories.

**What I have done:**

First, I fired the following query to retrieve all categories that do not have sub-categories and which are not a sub-category of other category:

```
 select from Cat where @rid not in (select @rid, expand(both('CatEdge')) from Cat)
```

Then, programatically, I loop through all the categories fetched and find their corresponding values:

```
select expand(out('ValEdge')) from Cat where category = 'FirstName'
```

Second, I fetch all the categories that have sub-categories or are itself a sub-category using:

```
select from (traverse out('CatEdge') from Cat) where out('CatEdge').size() > 0
```

And store it in a list called `SubList`.
The above query will give me 'Education' and 'College'.
Using this list, for each item, I check if there exists its sub-category using:

```
select expand(out('CatEdge')) from Cat where category = 'Education'
```

The above query will give 'School' and 'College'. Then, programmatically, I check if 'School' and 'College' exists in `SubList`.

> If it exists, I first remove it from the `SubList` and fire the above query again and this continues until I get zero rows.
>
> If it does not exists in `SubList`, then it is a 'leaf' category and then find its value in the `Val` Vertex.

As you may have noticed, this is getting too complex. Is there any other way that I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your situation:

```
create class Cat extends V
create property Cat.category string
create class CatEdge extends E

create class Val extends V
create property Val.value integer
create class ValEdge extends E

create vertex Cat set category = 'Education'
create vertex Cat set category = 'School'
create vertex Cat set category = 'College'
create vertex Cat set category = 'Bachelors'
create vertex Cat set category = 'Masters'

create vertex Val set value = 1
create vertex Val set value = 2
create vertex Val set value = 3

create edge CatEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'Education') to (select from Cat where category = 'School')
create edge CatEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'Education') to (select from Cat where category = 'College')
create edge CatEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'College') to (select from Cat where category = 'Bachelors')
create edge CatEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'College') to (select from Cat where category = 'Masters')

create edge ValEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'School') to (select from Val where value = 1)
create edge ValEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'Bachelors') to (select from Val where value = 2)
create edge ValEdge from (select from Cat where category = 'Masters') to (select from Val where value = 3)
```

[image]

And if I understood your intention correctly, this query will work:

```
select in("ValEdge").category, value from Val
```

Output:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**

```
select category, $subcategories, $value from Cat
let 
$subcategories = ( select category  from (traverse out('CatEdge') from $parent.$current ) where $depth >=1 ),
$value = ( select out('ValEdge').value as value from $current )
```

returns [this JSON](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/b87735ebd831b7d7f9c9).

Note that for all categories, or you have a list of subcategories, or, if it's a leaf, its value.

Comment: This will give me only the values of the 'leaf' categories. I also want to know the sub-categories of the categories if they exist.

Comment: You said: I want to retrieve all 'value' from Val for all the categories and sub-categories.
I don't understand what you want then.

Comment: Yes, apart from that, I want a list of categories and sub-categories if they exist. I am achieving that programmatically but want to know if that can be done using queries.

Comment: For what I understood, if they have value they don't have subcategories.

Or what you want is: For all (Sub)Categories, give me the list of all subcategories or if it's a leaf, the value.

Comment: Yes, this : For all (Sub)Categories, give me the list of all subcategories or if it's a leaf, the value.